# FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException after Firebase authentication migration

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

#### TL; DR

Is it possible the same Android app authenticate on both legacy and latest Firebase?

#### Description

We are refactoring an Android app that stills rely on [legacy Firebase framework](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/index.html) to the latest version of [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Unfortunately we have to authenticate on both framework versions calling simultaneously:

- [`FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth)
- [`Firebase.authWithPassword`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/index.html)

Even though the email/password works on the legacy API, the following error is thrown by the latest one:

```
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException:

    There is no user record corresponding to this identifier.
    The user may have been deleted.

        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzblv.zzce(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbls$zzj.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd.zzcf(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmd$zza.onFailure(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbly$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

So does it means it is not possible the same Android app authenticate on both legacy and latest Firebase?

Comment: Have you considered migrating your legacy users [using these tools](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#migrate_existing_logins)?

Comment: @BobSnyder The app does not use a repository pattern, consequently the access to the models are deeply tied to `com.firebase.client.Firebase` (more than 200 classes). We aim to refactor it into a repository incrementally, thus both authentications and snapshot access would have to coexist while we still rely on Firebase legacy.